# Intersection of cylinders

Tags: calculus, volume

Consider two infinite circular cylinders of equal radius whose axes meet in a right angle.

(a) What is the volume of their intersection?

(b) What is the area cut out of one by the other?

How to start this question?

Comment: The intersection can be seen as a stack of squares with dimensions that become less once you reach the top/bottom of the cylinders. In other words, there is a relation between the height inside the intersection and the size of a square.

Comment: For the surface area, you can integrate from the midpoint up to the top, and the angle will give you the length of surface intersected at each increment.

Comment: How about you start with equations that describe the cylinders.

Comment: If I had to guess without looking at the solution. I would say that you want to try and intersect the equations of the circles, but also work in an angle as well.

Answer (score 0):

Hint for a: Well,consider that if the axes of the 2 cylinders meet at at a right angle, this means the axes are perpendicular to each other. In other words, it looks like this:

[image]